# How do I uninstall a Fabric kit in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

I have a few kits installed but now I decided I do not want to use Digits & Twitter anymore. I deleted the frameworks manually but they keep popping up in the Fabric app and in my dashboard.

I've been looking everywhere but an option to remove or delete the kits seems to be non existent. I also didn't find anything in the documentation about this.

[image: Screenshot 1] [image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue as you. I tried wiping my DerivedData path and cleaning my build folder, but had no luck.

In the end the only thing that worked for me was deleting my App on Fabric and re-creating/re-installing it. I think the key step was removing the Run Script in Build Phases and re-adding it with the new key during the installation process.

I know it's not the best solution, but I can confirm that it works. The downside is if you had any other Kits installed (Answers, Beta, etc) I'm pretty sure you'll lose your data.

Comment: I have indeed Answers, Beta & Crashlytics and I don't want to lose this data. I tried deleting DerivedData as well but that doesn't solve it indeed. As I don't want to lose my existing data this is not really a helpful solution but I can imagine this does work and you don't really need the data.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting the files `DerivedData` path and clean build folder

```
cmd+opt+shift+k
```

then re run the application.

Also check once again the Framework search path in xcode settings.